# Как значение из динамического файла передать переменной на стороне клиента.[JS, jQuery]

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, token, hls

Имеется файл (**url**) который динамически обновляет значение токенов при каждом обновлении (**запросе**) и содержит внутри примерно такое:

```js
[{
    "_id": "someidlikewewsdw",
    "type": 1,
    "name": "Channelname1",
    "logo": "/static/logos/channellogo1.png",
    "thread": "https://somesite.com/Channelname1/video.m3u8?token=33121",
    "enabled": true
}, {
    "_id": "someidlikewewesq",
    "type": 1,
    "name": "Channelname2",
    "logo": "/static/logos/channellogo2.png",
    "thread": "https://somesite.com/Channelname2/video.m3u8?token=13121",
    "enabled": true
}, {
    "_id": "someidlikewewesd",
    "type": 1,
    "name": "Channelname3",
    "logo": "/static/logos/channellogo3.png",
    "thread": "https://somesite.com/Channelname3/video.m3u8?token=23121",
    "enabled": true
}]
```

Мне надо присвоить значение **"thread"** к переменной.
Допустим создать переменные Channel1token, Channel2token, Channel3token и присвоить им значения из theard каждого по отдельности.

var Channel1token = https://somesite.com/Channelname1/video.m3u8?token=33121 и тд.

Все это нужно в js что бы запросы шли от клиента, так как каждому клиенту присваивается отдельный токен.

Comment: AJAX? Что пробовали? Что не получилось? Если я правильно понимаю, то Вам нужно по AJAX запрашивать Ваш "файлоURL" и полученный ответ использовать дальше. В чём проблема то конкретно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то нужно из JSON выдрать отдельные threads. Проще всего их положить в массив. В этом случае для хрома/мозилы код будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
var channelTokens = [];

$.ajax({url: "feeds.json"})
 .done(function( data ) {
     data.forEach(feed => {
        channelTokens.push(feed.thread)
     });

console.log("We have tokens", channelTokens)
        });
```

Вместо console.log - можно уже обрабатывать дальше полученный результат.